# Problem with reference to another project

Tags: c#, reference

I have 1 solution with 2 projects (TcpClient and TcpServer) in TcpProtocol namespace.
Folders:
TestProject/source/TcpProtocol.Client/TcpClient.cs
TestProject/source/TcpProtocol.Server/TcpServer.cs

I have added this to the TcpClient project:

```
using static TcpProtocol.Server; // for use static values in TcpProtocol.Client.
```

But when I try to build a project, I get the following error message:
"The type or namespace 'Server' does not exist in the namespace 'TcpProtocol' (are you missing an assembl reference?)"
It's strange, because reference exist, but under name of reference I see yellow triangle.

If instead of using static write like this in code all work fine:
TcpProtocol.Server.port = 8008;

Why doesn't it work with static? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the TcpProtocol.Server perhaps Private? Also if you have yellow warnings under references. Check if your versions match.  There may be some dependency that's not supported.

Comment: If you mean the class access modifier no, it's public

Comment: The yellow Triangles(warnings) could simply be a framework mismatch. differing .NET Framework versions between the projects can cause this

Answer (score 0):

Never used that before but I would understand the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) that you have to target a type/class.

Your code sample seems to target a namespace...

Comment: I've added class name: TcpProtocol.Server.TcpServer, but doesn't work anyway. It's funny that when I click on the namespace mistake, the red line under my mistake disappears and the project starts working. However, if I make a clean solution and rebuild the project, then the error appears and disappears again when I enter the class with this error.

Comment: is there any message realtes to the namespace mistake or the orange triangle? maybe in the output or error view?

Comment: Besides what I wrote above, no. BUT, I don't know how, but my platforms were different, so I fixed it: Configuration Manager -> Platforms -> <New>... -> choose platform.